# Landscape View in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a customized `AlertDialog` in my activity. The problem is I want my activity only in `Portrait View`. So, I removed the landscape view from it. Now, I have alertdialog in same activity. I want this alertdialog to display in landscape view only. I searched for some function to set `AlertDialog` in landscape mode. I found "setRequestedOrientation" function, but it is for simple `Dialog`(not `AlertDialog`). I also found an attribute **screenOrientation** but it is for `Activity`.

Any idea how to set Landscape mode to `AlertDialog`?

Comment: make activity as dialog and set its orientation to landscape in manifest.and start activity onClick.

Comment: @Indiandroid Thanks for reply! Can't I set the AlertDialog to landscape?